# How to fix bootstrap dropdown menus that don't function

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have been using the bootstrap dropdown code as a template and it has been working until now. I have made sure every thing is up to date and now all my dropdowns are not working.

I have tried pasting the bootstrap code directly on my site and it still doesnt work. I updated my theme and now its broken.

It was working for weeks and now has stopped working.

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown mb-4" type="button" id="modelDropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="float-left" id="current-model">Finish</span>
    <span class="float-right"><i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i></span>
</button>

<div class="model-filter dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="modelDropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item all-models" href="#">Finish</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Paint</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Stain</a>
</div>
```

I want the dropdown to open when clicked

Comment: do you add `popper.js` in your project ?

Comment: if yes and still not working try to follow this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/

Comment: are there javascript errors in console?

Comment: did you 'update' the bootstrap link from bootstrap 3 to 4?

Comment: if that's the case, maybe the bootstrap 4 dropdowns use other/ extra classes to work

Comment: By any chance did you update jQuery from, perhaps, 2.x to 3.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the popper.js. I just had to add the popper.js line before closing the body.

Does anyone know why this would have been effected on an update?